# Error: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address. (E-mail address with postfix for outgoing mails)

Tags: c#, smtp

I am working in C# Email Sending.

I have no problems sending programmatic emails via SMTP using the normal e-mail address like 'myemail@exchange.com'.

But as per Company Policy, whenever they send e-mails outside the network, they add a postfix on the e-add like "myemail@exchange.com@yodachi".

So when I tried sending using that e-add format I get the error: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am using SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network since we are using SMTP thru company network.

Thanks,
Al

Edit: I've found out that the policy I am talking about is Lotus Domino Roaming. The postfix serves as a request on the Main Server to transfer a outgoing mail.

Comment: As the error clearly states, that's not a valid address.  That policy makes no sense.

Comment: Actually, when they are trying to send e-mails on Lotus Notes, they apply that policy (adding postfix) so they could send outgoing emails. They could not send outgoing e-mails when they do not add the postfix.

Comment: Well, you can't send outgoing emails with the postfix either; that violates all of the RFCs.

Comment: I can't send it programmatically, but on Lotus Notes, we could send.

Comment: @SLaks: maybe this policy is specific only to the company, in which maybe they set some configurations on which it is compulsory to add a postfix on every outgoing emails. So, is there a way we could disable or by-pass the checking of the e-mail format and just proceed with the sending?